# How to Navigate from One Page to Another in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `MainWindow.XAML` and `CustomersView.XAML`.

When I click the Customer Button on MainWindow , I want to navigate to `CustomersView.XAML` and palong with that need to pass few parameters.

I can use `NavigationService` but is only available with Pages and not Window.Hyperlink is not an option at this moment.

This might be fairly simple thing but not sure how can I implement this using MVVM and with out any third party control.

Answer (score 6):

```
private void Navigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//By Prince Jain 
{
   this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to provide an explanation on how your code sample works and helps the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to navigate from one window to another in WPF. You can use a frame in your `MainWindow` and navigate all your pages right inside your Frame.

```
<Window 
    x:Class="NavigationSample.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

From code, you can tell the frame to navigate, like so:

```
_mainFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
```

Which just so happens to be a helpful shortcut to:

```
_mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
```

Or if you using any framework like PRISM, you are allowed to create a Shell where you can define regions and let your pages navigate to that.

[Navigation Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Comment: Can I do this without using Frame?

Comment: This might help you. http://wpfplayground.com/2014/06/04/navigation-model-for-simple-mvvm-applications/

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way in XAML:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="continueButton" Width="75"
        Margin="0,0,8,11" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Click="continueButton_Click">
        Navigate
</Button>
```

C#:

```
private void continueButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.GoForward();
    //or
    this.NavigationService.Navigate("Second.xaml")
}
```

In MVVM XAML:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static Views:Commands.NavigateHelp}"
        Content="Help"/>
```

In Views (We have a `Commands.cs` file that contains all of these):

```
public static RoutedCommand NavigateHelp = new RoutedCommand();
```

In the page constructor, you can connect the two:

```
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(Commands.NavigateHelp,
    NavigateHelpExecute));
```

`NavigateHelpExecute` can be in the code behind (which is what we do), hook into a `ViewModel` event handler, or whatever. The beauty of this is that you can disable other navigation like so:

```
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.Refresh, null));
```

Comment: This.NavigationService is availabl eto WPF pages and not window, I need to navigate between WPF windows as mentioned on question

Comment: @Simsons http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee go throgh this link